# Taking form button input

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

So i'm using Flask to build a basic control panel for an IR Automation in my home. However I'm failing to understand how to take a response from the form in my HTML. So I basically have a button that changes the state of a device when pressed. The issue I'm having is taking that response and updating it on the HTML page to say it's on or off.

My python flask code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['lamp'] == 'on':
            btn1 = True
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((IP, PORT))
            s.send(MSG.encode())
            data = str(s.recv(BUFFER).decode())
            print(data)
            s.close()

        elif request.form['lamp'] == 'off':
            btn1 = False
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((IP, PORT))
            s.send(MSG.encode())
            data = str(s.recv(BUFFER).decode())
            print(data)
            s.close()
```

And the HTML part it works with:

```
                <form method=post>
                    {%  if btn1 == True  %}
                        <button type=submit class="btn btn-default" name="lamp" value="on"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-5x" style="color:yellow;"></i><br>Lamp</button>
                        {{  btn1  }}
                    {% else %}
                        <button type=submit class="btn btn-default" name="lamp" value="off"><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-5x"></i><br>Lamp</button>
                        {{  btn1  }}
                    {%  endif  %}
                </form>
```

Why isn't btn1's state changing when I click it?

Thanks,
James

Comment: because in both cases you are sending the same MSG ...you also would have to pass btn1 into the template renderer

Comment: @JoranBeasley Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: you need to call `render_template("my.html",btn1=True)` when you render your template you will also have to store the current button state in some kind of permanent cache since it probably will not persist between connections

Comment: But that would make the btn1 True everytime, what about when It's false? This button is a light switch, the light isnt always on, it will change, therefore it can't be True all the time....?

Comment: yes you would have to set it to the right value true or false I just used true in the example to show up passing variable new template looks like

Comment: Right ok, and then how to ensure the button updates on the HTML so it goes from say black to yellow? Because at the moment I have to refresh for it to take affect.

Answer (score 0):

really you should probably just be using json calls

**flaskapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
import json
app = Flask(__name__)
def load_data(flat_file):
    try:
        return json.load(open(flat_file))
    except (IOError,ValueError):
        return {}
db_file = "my_data.json"

@app.route("/lamp/on")
def lamp_on():
    data = load_data(db_file)
    data["lamp"] = "on"
    json.dump(data,open(db_file,"wb"))
    return json.dumps(data)

@app.route("/lamp/off")
def lamp_off():
    data = load_data(db_file)
    data["lamp"] = "off"
    json.dump(data,open(db_file,"wb"))
    return json.dumps(data)

@app.route("/status")
def status():
    return load_data(db_file).get("lamp","off")
@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template("template.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this app will provide an api to turn on and off the light (obviously you will want to do more than just write to a file).  as well as a visual dashboard at the "/" route

**template.html**

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">

</div>
</body>
<script>
    function OnButton(){
        var url = "/lamp/"+$("#lamp_btn").val().toLowerCase()
        $.get(url,update_button)
    }
    function update_button(){
        $.get("/status",function($data){
            var next_state = $data == "off"? "On":"Off"
            var button = $('<button id="lamp_btn" value="'+next_state+'">Turn Lamp '+next_state+'</button>')
            button.click(OnButton);
            $("#content").html(button)
        });
    }
    update_button();
</script>
```

this is the dashboard it just uses json calls to the api and updates just the button (but you could update much more... this is just a very simple example)